# Как загрузить файл FXML в статическом методе?

Tags: java, javafx

Мне нужно как-то сделать этот код рабочим. Я знаю, что нельзя задавать статическую ссылку на не статический метод `getClass()`:

```
public class Exercise{
    static Parent panel1;

    public static void start() throws Exception {
        Stage WindowExercise=new Stage();
        panel1=FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("src//application//Window1(Otgimanie).fxml")); 
        Scene scene1=new Scene(panel1,600,270);
        WindowExercise.setScene(scene1);
        WindowExercise.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем случае должно быть достаточно:

```
panel1=FXMLLoader.load(Exercise.class.getResource("src//application//Window1(Otgimanie).fxml"));
```

если путь правильный. Подозреваю, что надо все-таки "/application/Window1(Otgimanie).fxml", если файл лежит в пакете `application`.